# is it possible to setup elasticsearch on ceph block storage

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use ceph as storage backend for elasticsearch?
It seems to me that elasticsearch only supports disk writes. But I want to use my ceph cluster to be used as storage backend for the elasticsearch cluster

Answer (score 2):

We have been using it at my company. We have 3 elasticsearch nodes with ceph as storage. It usually ingests about 20,000 records per seconds (5-6 millions per 5 minutes) with the loads being around 1.5 - 2.5 on all nodes.

You need to make sure you have very fast local network though.

My setup: 
No of primary shards: 3
No of replica: 1

https://nayarweb.com/blog/2017/high-load-on-one-of-elasticsearch-node-on-ceph/